# How do I figure out the issue in unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value?

Tags: ios, swift

I keep getting error. 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I am thinking the issue is `var countOfObjects : Int!`
 could someone please point out the issue?

```
   var itemsorder = [String]()



    var tableView: UITableView!

    var countOfObjects : Int! // Holds count for query objects from Parse

    var allObjects : NSArray!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getDataFromParse() // A helper method to fetch data from Parse
        // Initialize for countOfObjects to 0 on viewDidLoad
        countOfObjects = 0
    }

    func getDataFromParse() {
        let query = PFQuery(className:"reservedCust")
        query.selectKeys(["items"])
        query.selectKeys(["username"])
        query.selectKeys(["time"])
        query.selectKeys(["userid"])

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object : [PFObject]?, error) -> Void in

           print(object!.count)
            print(object!)
            //set  count Of Objects
            self.countOfObjects = object?.count

            // Set allObjects
            self.allObjects = object

            //Reload TableView after query
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }





    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        return countOfObjects
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let mycell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("order", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! randomTableViewCell



        if let object = allObjects {
             let currentObject = object.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            mycell.textLabel?.text = (currentObject.objectForKey("items") as? String)
            print(valueForKey("items"))
            // Assign label text from parse.
        }

        return mycell

    }

}
```

Comment: Why even do `var countOfObjects : Int!` just do `var countOfObjects : Int = 0`

Comment: Any time you say `!` it means "crash me". So you can hardly be surprised when Swift obliges and does so.

Comment: That is a poor way to look at it,  ! simply means that this variable must have data associated with it, and is used whenever you want to read data that cannot be nil,  if it is nil, there is a flaw with logic,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at this code,  your problem is here  `self.tableView.reloadData()`  I see no spots that tableView is created.  Instead of:

```
var tableView: UITableView!

var countOfObjects : Int! // Holds count for query objects from Parse

var allObjects : NSArray!
```

do

```
var tableView = UITableView()

var countOfObjects : Int = 0 // Holds count for query objects from Parse

var allObjects = NSArray()
```

Comment: hi i tried. it still doesn't help. what did u mean that the problem is `self.allObjects = object` and `self.tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: I edited my answer, it is just the tableView.  You are trying to reload tableview, but it is nil.  `var tableView = UITableView()` should solve your problem since it will be non nil

Comment: If it fails after this answer,  then you need to provide the exact line it crashes at, because something is not being filled in with an object.

Comment: hi basically I'm trying to print out the values to a table. but it doesn't print it.

`if let object = allObjects {
             let currentObject = object.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            mycell.label.text = (currentObject.valueForKey("items") as? String)
           
        }
        
        return mycell`

Comment: I dont know much about table views,  are you even getting into the method that is calling the print

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are using a storyboard.  Once you create the UITableView, you need to programmatically add it to the appropriate view hierarchy.  For me, it is much simpler to use a storyboard and then link the table to its delegate and source. 

What is the class declaration for your code above?  Is this a subclass of UITableViewController?  You do not have the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method declared.

Once you have your table set up correctly, it will not refresh itself from a  background thread, which is where the Parse closure will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `countOfObjects` to be `Int!`, which means that you absolutely guarantee that the variable will always have a non-nil value once it has been initialized. Until it has been set the first time, it will have a value of `nil`. You should succeed if you simply declare it to be a regular Int and initialize it to 0.

`var countOfObjects: Int = 0`

You really do need a good reason to use implicitly unwrapped optionals (which `Int!` is), often when initializing interdependent classes or instances.  This is detailed here:
  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID334

Comment: Although this is true,  if you look at his code, he sets countOfObjects to a value before reading from it,  so countOfObjects is not the answer to his problem, the poster just doesn't know where he is looking,